# Race condition in recursive POSIX thread code?

Tags: c, multithreading, recursion, posix, race-condition

I'm writing code to calculate the integral of x^2+1 as POSIX C-Code, by cutting in half the parts recursively.

I know, I could use a library, it's just for studies.

---

e1 and e2 will be initialized in my main function, directly before calling integrate with parameters, like this:

```
e1 = 10E-2;
e2 = 2E-4;
integrate(1.0, 2.0)
```

The code looks like this:

```
float e1, e2;

float f(float x)
{
    return pow(x, 2) + 1;
}

float f1(float x)
{
    return 2 * x;
}

typedef struct integrateArgs
{
    float a;
    float b;
    float result;
} integrateArgs;

float integrate(float a, float b);
void* integrateAsThread(void* args)
{
    integrateArgs* myArgs = (integrateArgs*)args;
    myArgs->result = integrate(myArgs->a, myArgs->b);
    return NULL;
}

float integrate(float a, float b)
{
    float diff = b - a;
    if(a < 0 || a >= b || diff > 2 || e1 <= 0 || e2 <= 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    float x1 = (a + b) / 2;
    float x2 = f(x1);
    if((f1(x1) / x2) > e1 && diff > e2)
    {
        float half = diff / 2;
        float newCenter = a + half;

        integrateArgs rightPart = { .a = newCenter, .b = b };

        pthread_t thread;
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, integrateAsThread, (void*)&rightPart);
        float left = integrate(a, newCenter);
        pthread_join(thread, NULL);

        return left + rightPart.result;
    }
    else
    {
        return diff * x2;
    }
}
```

Although I do not have any guess where, there seems to be a race condition. If I change the integrate-method to:

```
float left = integrate(a, newCenter);
pthread_t thread;
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, integrateAsThread, (void*)&rightPart);
pthread_join(thread, NULL);
```

which in fact removes the parallelism, it works fine. If I use the first version, the result differs on each execution.

Any hints, what did I do wrong?

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem. Could you please add the bits that are missing to make runnable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not check the return value of `pthread_create`.  It is likely that your code creates too many threads, so that you exceed the operating system limit, and then some of the subtasks are never executed, and you get wrong results.

Comment: You were right. Actually it returned 35 as error code for some times. Based on [Linux System Errors](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html), this means "Resource deadlock would occur". Now that I handle that error, it works. Thank you!